# How to navigate to different views based on picker selection in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigation, picker

I have a SwiftUI app that has a picker with three options: View1, View2, and View3. I want to navigate to the corresponding view when I select one of the options. I am using NavigationStack to handle the navigation, but I don’t know how to link the picker selection to the navigation link. Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PickerViews: View {
    @State var selectedView = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Picker(selection: $selectedView, label: Text("Picko")){
                Text("View1")
                    .tag(0)
                Text("View2")
                    .tag(1)
                Text("View3")
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Picker")
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View1")
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View2")
    }
}

struct View3: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View3")
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the desired behavior? Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use onChange

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `NavigationStack` to a path array and then append the selected value to the array in an `.onChange` callback. Like this:

```swift
    @State private var navPath = [Int]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            Picker(selection: $selectedView, label: Text("Picko")){
                Text("View1")
                    .tag(0)
                Text("View2")
                    .tag(1)
                Text("View3")
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Picker")
            .onChange(of: selectedView) { newIndex in
                navPath.append(newIndex)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { index in
                switch index {
                case 1: View2()
                case 2: View3()
                default: View1()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that it only performs navigation when there is a change of selection. So if you navigate to View1, then navigate back, the `Picker` is still set to View1. If you want to navigate to View1 again then you first have to navigate to some other selection and back again. It also means that when you first land on the navigation page, it shows a selection which has no relevance.

Another approach would therefore be to have a "Go" button which goes to the selected selection, but this is perhaps a bit clumsy. You might as well just use `NavigationLink` instead.